# Play: Binary webservice response

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework-2.0

I have to call a webservice that gives me the content of a binary file. I just want to give the same content back to the caller of my controller:

```
val blobPromise = WS.url("http://url/to/webservice/file.txt").get()
Async {
  blobPromise.map(f => Ok(f.body))
}
```

This works for text files, but binary files will get corrupted. What I am doing wrong here? (Maybe it's the `f.body` that encodes the binary result from the webservice to a String? But how can I get the raw data?)

I know, it's not a good way for big files - I have read in the Play docs about [Streaming HTTP responses](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaStream), but it seems to complicated for me as a beginner with the Play framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the raw data using `f.ahcResponse.gerResponseBodyAsBytes`. But I think, this will load the entire response into memory, which is inefficient.

You can use the streaming functionality that Play! provides quite easily like this:

```
Async {
  WS.url("http://url/to/webservice/file.txt").get().map(response => {
    val asStream: InputStream = response.ahcResponse.getResponseBodyAsStream
    Ok.stream(Enumerator.fromStream(asStream))
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both solutions with `f.ahcResponse.getResponseBodyAsBytes` work now also with binary data. The streaming functionality seems to be easier than I have thought... :-)

Comment: In fact it doesn't block when you read from it... but only because it is read all into memory first. To avoid that, you would have to use the overloaded form of `get()` which takes a consumer function argument: `get[A](consumer: (ResponseHeaders) ⇒ Iteratee[Array[Byte], A])`

Comment: This code reads the whole in memory. If you need streaming, check a sample app: https://github.com/yanns/streamapp/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala#L78

Comment: There is an example of using WS with an Iteratee in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS under the "Processing Large Responses" header.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stream the content:

```
def streamFromWS = Action.async { request =>
  import play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent.joined

  val resultPromise = Promise[SimpleResult]

  val consumer = { rs: ResponseHeaders =>
    val (wsConsumer, stream) = joined[Array[Byte]]
    val contentLength = rs.headers.get("Content-Length").map(_.head).get
    val contentType = rs.headers.get("Content-Type").map(_.head).getOrElse("binary/octet-stream")
    resultPromise.success(
      SimpleResult(
        header = ResponseHeader(
          status = OK,
          headers = Map(
            CONTENT_LENGTH -> contentLength,
            CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"""attachment; filename="file.txt"""",
            CONTENT_TYPE -> contentType
          )),
        body = stream
      ))
    wsConsumer
  }

  WS.url("http://url/to/webservice/file.txt").get(consumer).map(_.run)

  resultPromise.future
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Yann Simon answer, here's a simple CORS proxy implementation that permits to stream downloaded remote files and stream them to the client.
It does not load all the file in memory.

```
  import play.api.libs.iteratee._

  private def getAndForwardStream(requestHolder: WSRequestHolder)(computeHeaders: ResponseHeaders => ResponseHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val resultPromise = scala.concurrent.Promise[SimpleResult]
    requestHolder.get { wsResponseHeaders: ResponseHeaders =>
      val (wsResponseIteratee, wsResponseEnumerator) = Concurrent.joined[Array[Byte]]
      val result = SimpleResult(
        header = computeHeaders(wsResponseHeaders),
        body = wsResponseEnumerator
      )
      resultPromise.success(result)
      wsResponseIteratee
    }
    resultPromise.future
  }

  def corsProxy(url: URL) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val requestHolder = WS.url(url.toString).withRequestTimeout(10000)
    getAndForwardStream(requestHolder) { wsResponseHeaders: ResponseHeaders =>
      // We use the WS response headers and transmit them unchanged to the client, except we add the CORS header...
      val originToAllow = request.headers.get("Origin").getOrElse("*")
      val headers = wsResponseHeaders.headers.mapValues(_.head) + ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> originToAllow)
      ResponseHeader(
        status = wsResponseHeaders.status,
        headers = headers
      )
    }
  }
```

The important part here is the use of `play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent.joined[Array[Byte]]`.
It permits to create an Iteratee/Enumerator pair so that whenever you add bytes to the Iteratee, these bytes will be enumerator by the enumerator.

This was the missing piece because:

- You need an Iteratee to consume the WS response.
- You need an Enumerator to produce the play framework response.

Comment: notice the new API stream() coming with play 2.3:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequestHolder

with it, you do not need joined[] anymore